# dynamic alias in T-SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've got an issue generating an alias for a field in a query which for example gives me the revenue from last year and the year before. I was in the understanding that I could do something like :

```
SELECT 
    1234 AS 'REVENUE' + CAST (year(DATEADD(year,-1,getdate())) AS VARCHAR(20))
    4321 AS 'REVENUE' + CAST (year(DATEADD(year,-2,getdate())) AS VARCHAR(20))
```

But this doesn't work. Does somebody know how to get this done?

I want to end up with a table like

```
rownr|revenue2014|revenue2013
-----------------------------
1    |1234       |4321
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

greets Niels

Comment: do you want the column name as revenue

Comment: no I just want it to say for example "REVENUE2014" and want that column to say "REVENUE2015" next year.

Comment: please give expected output in your question

Comment: Thats not what I mean, I'll edit my question.

Comment: I think you have to use dynamic sql to achieve what you want, unless you can solve your original problem in some other way

Comment: Unless you want to make the whole thing dynamic SQL, no. Any individual query always produces a result set with the same "shape" - the number of columns, their *names* and types are fixed.

Comment: Also, if this is being fed into something else (almost all queries are) such as a reporting tool or an application, performing the renaming *there* may be much easier than trying to do it in the SQL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(1000);
SET @sql = 'SELECT 
    1234 AS REVENUE' + CAST (year(DATEADD(year,-1,getdate())) AS VARCHAR(20)) + ',
    4321 AS REVENUE' + CAST (year(DATEADD(year,-2,getdate())) AS VARCHAR(20))
PRINT @sql
EXEC (@sql)
```

It is impossible to do that in the static SQL query. So only this way.

Comment: Thanks Dmitrij , can I write dynamics SQL in Views , I want to have dynamics alias in my View , because my views are used by thereporter.

Comment: no, you can't have dynamic views. Usually report tools themselves can pivot data, so you can implement that logic there