# count in dynamic name SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I create a stored procedure in SQL Server:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[testChildren]
    @Parent INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    WITH EntityChildren AS
    (
         SELECT 
             nname, nodeid, level, ncode, nparent
         FROM 
             GrpItm
         WHERE 
             nodeid = @Parent

        UNION ALL

        SELECT 
            e.nname, e.nodeid, e.level, e.ncode, e.nparent
        FROM 
            GrpItm e
        INNER JOIN 
            EntityChildren e2 ON e.nparent = e2.nodeid
    )
    SELECT COUNT(Level) AS [level]
    FROM EntityChildren 
END
```

How can I make each count level in row and named the row by level value like this:

```
| level 1 | level 2 | level 3 |
+---------+---------+---------+
|    2    |    3    |    1    |
```

Comment: You can't have a dynamic number of columns in SQL.  The only way to achieve that is to have code that writes the SQL for you, then execute that dynamically generated SQL.  *(Look up `dynamic-sql` and use of `spexecute_sql`.)*

Comment: can i make column rows??

Comment: Your question is duplicated, get look at this [dynamic alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29510598/dynamic-alias-in-t-sql-query)

Comment: this Answer didn't work with me

Comment: When things descends in stuff like "dynamic columns" most of times it's not a sql problem but a logic problem in the way you consume the DB and present data to user. Those kind of problem is, in general, better addressed in BL and UX layers

Answer (score 1):

If you want something closer to...

```
 level | count
-------+-------
    1  |   2
    2  |   3
    3  |   1
```

Then it would just be something like...

```
SELECT
    level,
    COUNT(*)    AS row_count
FROM
    EntityChildren
GROUP BY
    level
```

But that's simpler than what you're already accomplished, so I may be missing the point of your question and comment?

Comment: I can do this how make column to be rows

Comment: I don't understand what you just asked.  You asked a question and in my comment I explained that you can't without "code-that-writes-sql" *(dynamic-sql)*, and even gave you the key words to search for.  You then asked me `can i make column rows??`, which I assumed was asking for the answer I just gave.  So, I re-itterate, ***you can't get what you wanted in your original question in normal SQL***...

Comment: If you want 3 columns *(for counts over 3 levels)* then you need a query with 3 expressions in the `SELECT`.  If you want 4 columns *(for counts over 4 levels)* then you need a query with 4 expressions in the `SELECT`.  Each time you want another column, you need a different query to be written.  There are ***no SQL queries*** that can change the number of columns they return dependent on the data. That's what ***rows*** are for, and why relational databases are structured *(normalised)* as they are.  You're trying to do something SQL and relational databases are ***not*** designed to do.

Comment: Nice answer - If he really wants to make it complicated he can take your result and unpivot it dynamically. But thats another story.

Comment: @plaidDK how can i do it?

Comment: I already answered that for you...  Look up Dynamic SQL.  Code that writes new SQL each time you run it.

Comment: Sorry i meant pivot not unpivot :)

Answer (score 1):

This is only regarding to @MatBailie answer. If you have a table like his, you can pivot your data and get it as you request.

**Table Created with Levels and counts**

> You need a script to populate this table with the values you need

```
create table dbo.myt (levels int, counts int)

insert into dbo.myt
values 
    (1 , 2),
    (2 , 3),
    (3 , 1)
```

**SQL Code**

```
DECLARE @ALIASNAME nvarchar(50) = 'Levels'
    DECLARE @Str NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @Str2 NVARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @Str = STUFF(
                   (
                       SELECT DISTINCT
                              ','+'[Levels'+cast(levels as nvarchar(50))+']'
                       FROM dbo.myt FOR XML PATH('')
                   ), 1, 1, '');
PRINT @Str
SET @str2 = N'select * from (
   select cast('''+@ALIASNAME+'''+ cast(Levels as nvarchar(50)) as nvarchar(50)) as Levels,counts,ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION by levels order by counts) as rn
   from dbo.myt
   )x
   PIVOT 
   (Max(counts) FOR Levels in ('+@Str+')
   ) as p';
PRINT @Str2;
EXEC (@Str2);
```

**Your Stored proc**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[testChildren]
    @Parent INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    WITH EntityChildren AS
    (
         SELECT 
             nname, nodeid, level, ncode, nparent
         FROM 
             GrpItm
         WHERE 
             nodeid = @Parent

        UNION ALL

        SELECT 
            e.nname, e.nodeid, e.level, e.ncode, e.nparent
        FROM 
            GrpItm e
        INNER JOIN 
            EntityChildren e2 ON e.nparent = e2.nodeid
    )

    INSERT INTO dbo.myt (Levels,Counts)
    SELECT
    level, COUNT(*)    AS row_count
    FROM
    EntityChildren
    GROUP BY level 


    /* INSERT PIVOT SCRIPT AND INSERT INTO A NEW TABLE */

END
```

**Result**

[image]