# Using a distinct value from table as an Alias

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, dynamic

I've got a view that is a bunch of survey responses. The structure of which is something like the below (excluding the Q1Text and Q2Text).

```
Q1     | Q1Text   | Q2     | Q2Text
Value1 | Q1Header | Value1 | Q2Header
Value1 | Q1Header | Value2 | Q2Header
Value3 | Q1Header | Value3 | Q2Header
```

What I would like is for the Q1Text, which is a grabbing it's values from a seperate field, to be the alias for Q1.

The values for Q1Text is the same value regardless of how many rows there are, and the same for Q2Text

I was told by a colleague to try dynamic SQL, but not sure if my lack of understanding wasn't allowing me to do it or what, but one of my many attempts of this is below. Might give you a better idea if what i'm after.

```
DECLARE @table NVARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Q1 NVARCHAR(128)
SET @table = '[MyTable]'
SET @Q1 = 'Select distinct P1Q1Qtext from' + @table
SET @sql = 'Select P1Q1 as ' + @Q1 + ' FROM ' + @table
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Question was answered before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29510598/dynamic-alias-in-t-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were storing query in variable @Q1 but not executing it.

```
DECLARE @table NVARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Q1 NVARCHAR(128)
SET @table = '[MyTable]'
SET @Q1 = (Select distinct top 1 P1Q1Qtext from MyTable)
SET @sql = 'Select P1Q1 as [' + @Q1 + '] FROM ' + @table
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: This will get the text `Select top 1 distinct P1Q1Qtext from MyTable` in the column title, and not the result from that query. And this error: `Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line ..
Invalid column name 'select top .....`

Comment: This worked great. Was so close yet so far. 

To expand on this, would it be possible to select distinct from @table on @Q1?

    ````SET @table = '[MyTable]````  

    ````SET @Q1 = Select top 1 distinct P1Q1Qtext from @table````



Sorry about the formatting. Tried about 5 times now to get it right..

Comment: @Luuk Yes i have misplaced top1 and distinct keywords.

Comment: The distinct is completely useless here, because of the top 1.